# PostgreSQL regexp.replace all unwanted chars

Tags: postgresql

I have registration codes in my PostgreSQL table which are written messy, like MU-321-AB, MU/321/AB, MU 321-AB and so forth...
I would need to clear all of this to get MU321AB.

For this I uses following expression:

```
SELECT DISTINCT regexp_replace(ccode, '([^A-Za-z0-9])', ''), ...
```

This expression work as expected in 'NET' but not in PostgreSQL where it  'clears' only first occurrence of unwanted character.

How would I modify regular expression which will replace all unwanted chars in string to get clear code with only letters and numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `g`lobal flag, but without any capture groups:

```
SELECT DISTINCT regexp_replace(ccode, '[^A-Za-z0-9]', '', 'g'), ...
```

Note that the global flag is part of the standard regular expression parser, so .NET is not following the standard in this case. Also, since you do not want anything extracted from the string - you just want to replace some characters - you should not use capture groups `()`.

Comment: Hi, Patrick Thanks for your answer. I remove "capture groups", add a 'g' flag and example works well, as expected. But one more issue appears. Can postgreSQL's regex be unicode so it can take such characters like "ü", "š" and so? If can how would regular expression look like?

Comment: Yes, that is possible by using the code point for the character in question in the _pattern_ string, such as `\u00F3` for "ü" and `\u0161` for "š". But you will understand that this can become rather tedious very quickly. See also http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html for more generic (non-PG specific) information. I specifically do not know if _Unicode scripts_ or _blocks_ work in PG such that you could match all Latin-Extended characters in one swoop.

Comment: OK, thanks again. I added upper and lower unicodes in pattern and for my actual purpose this work's well. I would surelly need to read about regexes...